# Wordpress theme broken after move from old hosting to new

Tags: wordpress, migration

I am working on https://riversheen.com/ and I moved the website from old to new server.
The website layout is broken.
The theme I am using is EVENTOX.

Comment: To move a website from one place to another please use the "duplicator" plugin, is easy to use, and free! Probably will solve your migration problem

Comment: I don't have access to the old server now